# How to throw SQLException in a DAO-layer

Tags: java, code-coverage, dao

I want to test DAO class with JUnit. The test coverage is 80%, so nearly every line of code is covered except the catch clauses for SQLException. I have no idea how I can provoke a SQLException

```
 public void removeStudentFromCourse(Integer studentId, Integer courseId) {
        try (Connection connection = connector.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
                     DELETE_STUDENT_FROM_ONE_COURSE_QUERY)) {
            statement.setInt(1, studentId);
            statement.setInt(2, courseId);
            statement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DBException("Can`t remove student with id: " + studentId +
                    " from course with id:" + courseId, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: how about passing non-existing studentId?

Comment: Hello, you can use Mockito. You have an example to throw the exception : https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-exceptions

Comment: @IKo That will result in no update, not an exception.

Comment: According to the doc of PreparedStatement https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate() "SQLException - if a database access error occurs; this method is called on a closed PreparedStatement or the SQL statement returns a ResultSet object". Means you would have to mock your connector. As @stacy said you can do that with mockito. One thing you could consider is if you really want to catch the SQLException here. Since it should only occur if you have a config problem such as a wrong connection string.

Comment: I think testing the catch part may be worth the time in some case (for instance, checking that we correctly handle exception, or that they are no issue with the catch block - you would not want a NPE over a SQLException :)). The OP however wants to achieve best coverage (as I understand from _The test coverage is 80%, so nearly every line of code is covered except the catch clauses for SQLException_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That where you have to cheat a little:

- Have you connector object (whatever it is) be a mock
- Have the mock returns a mocked `Connection`
- Have the mocked `Connection` returns a mocked `PreparedStatement`
- Have the mocked `PreparedStatement` fails by throwing a `SQLException`.

With mockito this could be:

```
// case 1
when(connector.getConnection()).thenThrow(SQLException.class); 
// case 2
Connection cnx = mock(Connection.class);
when(cnx.prepareStatement(anyString()).thenThrow(SQLException.class); 
when(connector.getConnection()).thenReturn(cnx);
when(connector.getConnection()).thenThrow(SQLException.class);
```

Comment: Mocking is the right approach and I agree with NoData and Stacky's recommendation of Mockito to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could

- have a connection that throws `SQLException` on call to `getConnection()`
- have a connection that produces a mock PreparedStatement which throws an `SqlException` on one of teh methods that are called, like `setInt()` or `executeUpdate()`, or
- overwrite `DELETE_STUDENT_FROM_ONE_COURSE_QUERY` to be an invalid SQL statement.